# Equivalent of creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE on Linux for Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess, popen

I have a working code on Windows that features the following line:

`subprocess.Popen(["python", os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'Dependencies/Dash.py'), arg[0], arg[1]], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`

that lets me open a new console where the script `Dash.py` is ran with arguments `arg[0]` and `arg[1]` passed to it. This lets me close the new console when I have no more use for it so I can run another console for the same script with different arguments.

However, now I want to be able to use my code on linux but `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` is Windows-exclusive. I have looked around and one of the solutions suggested is to use `shell=True`.

When I use `subprocess.Popen(["python", os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'Dependencies/Dash.py'), arg[0], arg[1]], shell=True)` on Linux though, no new console is being opened when I run the code. The initial console is the only one that is appearing the whole time.

What is the best method to recreate on Linux what `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` is doing on Windows?

edit:

I have managed to make it work by using the following so I just wanted to share in case anybody would find it useful later:

```
to_run = 'python \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"'.format(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'Dependencies/Dash.py'), arg[0], arg[1])
subprocess.Popen(['xfce4-terminal', '-e', to_run])
```

Comment: What about opening the terminal application of your linux distribution? Take, for example, the [gnome-terminal in Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html).

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I have tried a solution that suggested to use ```subprocess.Popen(['xfce4-terminal', '-e', 'python path_to_script'], stdout=PIPE)``` but I have trouble figuring out how to pass the arguments when using that line

Comment: After the `path_to_script` in `python path_to_script`.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I have added them after the path and I basically have the same problem. There's no second console opening